# Render Script bundle from other application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bundling-and-minification

I am authoring an MVC application that is hosted by another MVC hosting solution. The dll from the client app is copied into the bin folder of the hosting app. The Views, Views/Shared, Scripts, Content, ... are all copied to the hosting project as well. In the Hosting solution, I've created an Area that will act as the base for any of the client apps and dynamically create routes to the view via a warmup routine. This part works great.

However, my javascript bundles do not render as I would hope, I believe it is because they files aren't being found. In this client app, I have two JS files...for simplicity's sake, `javascript1.js` and `javascript2.js`. The are located in my Scripts folder of my client app: `C:\MyClientApp\Scripts\*.js`. Upon compilation, a post build event copies the files to the Hosting solution: `C:\MyHostingApp\Scripts\MyClientApp\*.js`.

In an app startup (also done in the warmup routine), my bundle is built:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyClientApp.AppStart), "Start")]

namespace MyClientApp
{
    public static class AppStart
    {
        public static void Start()
        { 
            ConfigureBundles();
        }  

        private static void ConfigureBundles()
        {
            var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/MyClientApp/Js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/javascript1.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/javascript2.js");

            BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle); 
        }
    }    
}
```

In my view, I would like to call `@Scripts.Render("~/MyClientApp/Js")`. This doesn't work though, nothing is rendered. My assumption is that it is looking for that bundle under the root of the application, not under the `MyClientApp`. In an attempt to properly locate the bundle, I tried writing an HtmlHelper extension to resolve the bundle...though the best I could get it to do was to resolve the bundle name into my source and ultimately it seemed that there must be a simpler way to accomplish this. Any ideas on how to render these bundles? Is there something I can do with the routing engine, comparable to Views to locate JS (and eventually css) files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundling currently uses a VirtualPathProvider to find the files for the bundles.  The built in VirtualPathProvider only knows about files within the application.  If you want to be able to reference files outside of the app, you could try implementing your own VPP that can retrieve files outside of the app.